# How do you get a datetime_picker field in an edit view to display the value using the ActiveRecord configured timezone and not database's UTC value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, datetimepicker

I'm using `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'`. When I create new records, it converts the datetime to UTC and stores it okay in the database. In my show.html.erb it displays it in -0600 just fine. However, when ***editing*** an existing Event object, the _form.html.erb displays the datetime in UTC without converting to CST.

I've troubleshot a ton and have googled all over, but am truly lost. My understanding is that the only field type to display it correctly is datetime_select.

EDIT: The code I'm having trouble with is:

```
<%= f.datetime_picker :start_date, :dateFormat => 'yy-mm-dd', :showOn => "both", :minDate => DateTime.now, :buttonImageOnly => true, :buttonImage => "/images/calendar_icon.png", :class => "span2" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the time zone, you could get away with using `Time.zone.parse(field_name)` wherever you're trying to display it.

Edit: If you want it to display like that in the edit screen you could always format it in your edit action in your controller so its formatted in the form properly.